# XCode 8 enable indexing

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I tried the following two commands in the terminal window with sudo and also restarting the machine and Xcode, and indexing didn't turn on.

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable
```

and

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 0
```

I have a swift project and indexing does not turn on when I clean the project.  What am I doing wrong?